# Get all rows from left table and remove duplicate row on basis of other column's value

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, left-join

**Scenario :** I am having one Master table for Salary Heads i.e Basic, HRA, Cnveyance... etc. `[Columns are : ID, SalaryHeadName]`

And 1 transaction table for keeping salary records for each candidate. `[Columns are : CandidateID, SalaryHeadID, Amount]`

Now I want to list out all Salary Heads on a candidate's profile page where user will see All heads and a editable textbox in front of that heads.

If transaction table contains the Amount for particular Salary Head for that particular Candidate, I'll fill the amount or else that textbox will be blank.

My Query till now :

```
WITH cte as
(
Select ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount, DENSE_RANK () over (order by SalaryHeadName desc) as DenseRank 
from VW_GetSalaryStructureData 
where CandidateID = 145 or CandidateID is null 
GROUP BY  ID,SalaryHeadName,Amount

)

SELECT
    ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount, COUNT(Amount) as cnt
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount
```

SAMPLE DATA FROM BOTH TABLES :

[Salary Head table's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdpxN.jpg)

```
 ID SalaryHeadName  MainHead    Description CreatedDate CreatedBy
    1   BASIC   BASIC   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.080 1
    2   HRA HRA GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.080 1
    3   Conveyance  Conveyance  GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.080 1
    4   Medical Allowance   Medical Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.080 1
    5   City Compensation Allowance City Compensation Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.083 1
    6   Books N Periodicals Allowance   Books N Periodicals Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.083 1
    7   Entertainment Allowance Entertainment Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.083 1
    8   Attire Allowance    Attire Allowance    GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.083 1
    9   Mobile Allowance    Mobile Allowance    GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.087 1
    10  Supplementary Allowance Supplementary Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.087 1
    11  Leave Allowance Leave Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.087 1
    12  Bonus   Bonus   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.087 1
    13  Child Education Allowance   Child Education Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.090 1
    14  Washing Allowance   Washing Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.090 1
    15  Other Allowance Other Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.090 1
    16  Telephone Allowance Telephone Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.090 1
    17  Bonus (ESIC)    Bonus (ESIC)    GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.090 1
    18  Daily Allowance Daily Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.093 1
    19  Educational Allowance   Educational Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.093 1
    20  Performance Allowance   Performance Allowance   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.093 1
    21  Transport Allowance Transport Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.093 1
    22  Vehicle N Maintenance Allowance Vehicle N Maintenance Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.097 1
    23  Driver Salary Allowance Driver Salary Allowance GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.097 1
    24  Business Development Allowance  Business Development Allowance  GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.097 1
    25  LTA LTA GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.097 1
    26  Gross   Gross   GROSS   2018-05-25 16:40:06.097 1
    27  Gratuity CTC    Gratuity CTC    CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.100 1
    28  Leave Salary Allowance  Leave Salary Allowance  CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.100 1
    29  Bonus CTC   Bonus CTC   CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.100 1
    30  GPA GPA CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.100 1
    31  EPF EPF CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.100 1
    32  ESI ESI CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.103 1
    33  CTC CTC CTC 2018-05-25 16:40:06.103 1
    34  PF  PF  NET 2018-05-25 16:40:06.103 1
    35  ESI ESI NET 2018-05-25 16:40:06.103 1
    36  PT  PT  NET 2018-05-25 16:40:06.107 1
```

[Transaction table's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb16d.jpg)

```
ID  CandidateID SalaryHeadID    Amount  CreatedDate CreatedBy
1   151 1   15201   2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
2   151 2   1520    2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
3   151 3   2510    2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
4   151 6   1500    2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
5   151 26  50151   2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
6   151 33  434 2018-06-11 11:03:07.587 1
7   184 1   23233   2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
8   184 2   5455    2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
9   184 3   4343    2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
10  184 26  50151   2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
11  184 33  434 2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
12  154 1   23233   2018-06-21 11:10:37.263 1
13  154 2   5455    2018-06-21 11:10:37.263 1
14  154 3   4343    2018-06-21 11:10:37.263 1
15  154 26  50151   2018-06-21 11:10:37.263 1
16  154 33  434 2018-06-21 11:10:37.263 1
17  145 1   23233   2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
18  145 2   5455    2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
19  145 3   4343    2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
20  145 26  50151   2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
21  145 33  434 2018-06-21 11:09:12.627 1
```

And result for that query is :

[Please click to see the Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l25FZ.jpg)

Now, What I want is to remove duplicate rows with `NULL` values and list out all SalaryHeads only once.

Desired Result : 
[I want to remove red highlighted rows from result if Candidate is having amount in transaction table, otherwise all heads with null amount, Please click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYJlU.jpg)

**[Desired result on HTML page, I am developing in MVC 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNwGC.jpg)**

Comment: Please share some sample data for both the tables.

Comment: May advice - remove the redundant first paragraph it adds nothing and shows you up as whiney. Show inline results you are getting, show what you want to get. Then your question will be able to be grasped more readily and you'll get a speedier answer

Comment: @ShyamVemula please check sample data I have edited question

Comment: @AzeemShaikh Bro. What about sample Output.

Comment: @ShyamVemula 'Please click to see the Result:' this text is having link result of my posted query

Comment: never put sample data as pictures. We want to create temp tables to test your scenario and nobody will type over stuff from pictures. Add sample data as text

Comment: @AzeemShaikh Please go through the Answer. Don't think Broadly, Just `Left join` is enough your need I think.

Answer (score 0):

The query below should return an expected result.

```
BEGIN

WITH cte as ( Select ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount, DENSE_RANK () over (order by SalaryHeadName desc) as DenseRank  from VW_GetSalaryStructureData  where CandidateID = 145 or CandidateID is null  GROUP BY  ID,SalaryHeadName,Amount

)

SELECT
    ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount, COUNT(Amount) as cnt INTO #RESULT_TABLE FROM
    cte GROUP BY
    ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount;

WITH RM_DUPL AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT NULLS LAST) AS RN,  ID,SalaryHeadName, Amount, cnt FROM #RESULT_TABLE) SELECT  FROM RM_DUPL  WHERE RN = 1 or AMOUNT IS NOT NULL; END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone knows that the UNION operator removed duplicates. That comes in handy when you want to deduplicate data. As follows:

```
 SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
 FROM TableWithDuplicates
 UNION
 SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
 FROM TableWithDuplicates
```

Result is a deduplicated result set of TableWithDuplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following Query will fulfill your need mentioned on Desired output Image.

```
SELECT SH.Id SalaryHeadId, SH.SalaryHeadName, ISNULL(Tr.Amount, 0.00) PerMonth, 
ISNULL(Tr.Amount, 0.00)*12 PerAnnum
FROM Sal_Head SH
LEFT JOIN Transaction_Table Tr ON SH.Id = Tr.SalaryHeadId
WHERE Tr.CandidateId = 145
```